# How do i record audio from the speakers output using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I could not find any answer yet to my question after hours. I've been able recording from **microphone** only. What i want is, **Recording from the speakers (Internal)**.
The idea is a virtual piano which i recently working on it, And users should be able to record what they play.

Here is my code:

```
const record = ()=> {

  console.log('recording started...')

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then( stream => {

      const MEDIA_RECORDER = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      MEDIA_RECORDER.start();

      const AUDIO_CHUNKS = [];

      MEDIA_RECORDER.addEventListener('dataavailable',e => {
        AUDIO_CHUNKS.push(e.data);
      })

      MEDIA_RECORDER.addEventListener('stop',() =>
      {
        const AUDIO_BLOB = new Blob(AUDIO_CHUNKS);
        const AUDIO_URL  = URL.createObjectURL(AUDIO_BLOB);
        const AUDIO = new Audio(AUDIO_URL);
        
        AUDIO.play();
        
      })
      setTimeout(()=>{
        MEDIA_RECORDER.stop();
        alert('Recording done!')
      },3000)
    })
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish it? Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do this without installing other audio devices (like SoundFlower). Instead of trying to hook into the system's audio output like this, you should consider refactoring your piano app's code so that it can send it's audio output somewhere that can be saved.

Comment: The `mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` method opens the prompt that allows the user to choose between microphone or internal soundcard (and also video inputs if video is enabled in constraints), would that be acceptable in your case ? Also `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` returns an array of mediaInfos and could allow to identify the device you want to interact with..

Comment: It did not ask to choose between internal or mic. Thanks for your answer @Peterrabbit I appreciate you.

Comment: @Aqilhex Sadly there is no direct way to do that for security reasons. You are using the API `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` which created this for privacy reasons.